# Unable to 'getRecords' with SOAP to ServiceNow with VBA, getting Error: 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: vba, soap, servicenow

The below is code to get records via SOAP from *ServiceNow* from an `Incident` table.

I am getting **Error:500 Server internal error**.

I need my code to get all the records belonging to a specific assignment group, perferably query multiple assignment groups at once.

```
Dim sName, sEndpointURL, sResponsePath
Dim oWSRequest, oWSRequestDoc, oWSResponseDoc
Dim oWSRequestEnvelope, oWSRequestBody, oWSRequestOperation

Public Sub SetName(name)
    ' This function must be called BEFORE Post to initialize the class
    sName = name
    URL = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    sEndpointURL = gServiceNowURL & sName & ".do?SOAP"
    sResponsePath = "/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/executeResponse/"
    Set oWSRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Set oWSRequestDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    Set oWSRequestEnvelope = oWSRequestDoc.createElement("soap:Envelope")
    oWSRequestEnvelope.setAttribute "xmlns:soap", _
                                    URL
    Set oWSRequestBody = oWSRequestDoc.createElement("soap:Body")
    Set oWSRequestOperation = oWSRequestDoc.createElement("tns:execute")
    oWSRequestOperation.setAttribute "xmlns:tns", _
                                     "http://www.service-now.com/" & sName
    oWSRequestDoc.appendChild oWSRequestEnvelope
    oWSRequestEnvelope.appendChild oWSRequestBody
    oWSRequestBody.appendChild oWSRequestOperation
End Sub

Public Function Post()
    ' This function does the actual Web Services call
    oWSRequest.Open "POST", sEndpointURL, False, gServiceNowUser, gServiceNowPass
    oWSRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    oWSRequest.send oWSRequestDoc.XML
    If oWSRequest.Status = 200 Then
        Set oWSResponseDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
        oWSResponseDoc.LoadXML oWSRequest.responseText
        oWSResponseDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
        oWSResponseDoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", _
                                   "xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'"
        Post = True
    Else
        Set oWSResponseDoc = Nothing
        Post = False
    End If
End Function

Public Function Status()
    'If Post returns False call this function to obtain the HTTP status code
    Status = oWSRequest.Status
End Function

Public Function StatusText()
    ' If Post returns False then call this function for the error text
    StatusText = oWSRequest.StatusText
End Function

Public Sub SetValue(fieldname, fieldvalue)
    ' This function must be called BEFORE Post
    Dim oChild
    Set oChild = oWSRequestDoc.createElement(fieldname)
    oChild.appendChild (oWSRequestDoc.createTextNode(fieldvalue))
    oWSRequestOperation.appendChild (oChild)
End Sub

Public Function GetValue(fieldname)
    ' This function must be called AFTER Post
    GetValue = oWSResponseDoc.SelectSingleNode(sResponsePath & fieldname).Text
End Function
```

Comment: Is there anyway to get the resulting XML Document string and paste it here? Compare that with one generated from the WSDL by something like SoapUI.

Comment: Are you sure that's the request payload? It looks more like a response payload.

Comment: Request sent via SOAPUI:
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"; xmlns:inc="http://www.service-now.com/incident">;

   <soapenv:Header/>

   <soapenv:Body>

      <inc:getKeys>

      <inc:assignment_group>EMEA CIB INFRA GSDC Collaborative L2</inc:assignment_group>

      </inc:getKeys>

   </soapenv:Body>

</soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: Response recieved in SOAPUI
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"; xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">;
<env:Header>
<a:RelatesTo>Id-6e47a857ae010000a0010000061df3d5</a:RelatesTo>
</env:Header>
<env:Body>
<env:Fault>
<env:Code>
<env:Value>env:Sender</env:Value>
<env:Subcode>
<env:Value>500</env:Value>
</env:Subcode>
</env:Code>
<env:Reason>

            <env:Text xml:lang="en">Endpoint Connection Failed</env:Text>

         </env:Reason>

      </env:Fault>

   </env:Body>

</env:Envelope>